# Is there any way to INSERT and SELECT /connect to a database from another website?

Tags: php, database

Is there any way I can create codes and connect user databases/phpmyadmin via mysql_connect together.

Ex:

```
website1.com
website2.com

website1.com has login information
website2.com has media information for those users in website1.com
```

Is there any way to connect, confirm, insert/edit website1.com database table while using another website, website2.com? website2.com is essentially just confirming website1.com user data and using it to give access and give login confirm for website2.com.

Comment: Have you tried making a second connect to the 2nd database and retrieve data from it ?

Comment: You can use mysql_connect to connect a mysql db anywhere you have accounts to do so and can actually reach. However, mysql_*() functions are DEPRECATED and OBSOLETE, so you shouldn't be using them at all. And major nitpick: phpmyadmin is a management suite for mysql. it is not a database itself.

Comment: @MarcB Are you meaning to say that I need to use mysqli_*()? Because if so, I am already doing that. I was just using mysql to ask the question. Because, in a way, mysql is mysqli, just improved. ;P

Comment: Either enable remote SQL connection from website1.com control panel or develop and then use a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers to your question.

The best solution - but it's non-trivial - is to implement a [single sign-on framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). This is perfectly [possible in PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/ijansch/building-an-sso-platform-in-php-zendcon-2010) - and there are [libraries](https://github.com/openid/php-openid) you can use.

In this model "website 1" would become an OpenID provider, and "Website 2" an OpenID client. It's the same technology Stack Overflow uses to allow you to sign in with your GMail account.

It's "best" because you are building on top of proven, secure code, you're not exposing any sensitive information to the wider internet, and the framework answers many common questions like "okay, now I know you are who you claim to be, how do I find out what rights you should have?".

If you can guarantee the security of the connection between website 1's database and website 2 - i.e. they are hosted in the same network, with a firewall protecting them from the internet - you can just specify the host of website 1's database when connecting from website 2. You could also use [federated storage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) - but you probably want a DBA to help with that.

Whilst the MySQL route is possibly easier to accomplish, please note you should never, ever expose a MySQL port to the wider internet - most websites are under fairly persistent port scanning attacks, and as soon as an attacker spots a MySQL prompt, they will try to get into your database; if that database stores user credentials, they hit the jackpot.